# Fit a convolution in python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, convolution

I am a bit confused about convolutions in python. I tried to define this function:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x,A,t,mu,sigma):
    y1 = A*np.exp(-x/t)
    y2 = A*np.exp(-0.5*(x-mu)**2/sigma**2)
    return signal.convolve(y1,y2)/ sum(y2)

x = np.arange(-10,10,0.01)
```

x has dimension 2000, but f(x) seems to have size 3999 and I am not sure to what values of x this corresponds. In principle I want to fit this function (a convolution of a gaussian and exponential) like this:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x_data, y_data)
```

but I am kinda stuck, as I am not even sure on how to call the fitted values (assuming this would work), given that f(x_data) will be bigger than x_data. Can someone help me a bit here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`scipy` is using [numpy.convolve](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) to calculate the convolution. If you provide no `mode` argument, the default is `full`:

> ‘full’:
> By default, mode is ‘full’. This returns the convolution at each point of overlap, with an output shape of (N+M-1,). At the end-points of the convolution, the **signals do not overlap completely, and boundary effects may be seen**.

This is why the `full` mode gives adds this "extra" points. You can also have a look in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution).

I think what you are probably looking for is the mode `same`, since you probably do not care about the boundary effects. So I would recommend to change the return of your function to:

```
 return signal.convolve(y1,y2, 'same')/ sum(y2)
```